# Excel VBA function to print an array to the workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I've written a macro that takes a 2 dimensional array, and "prints" it to equivalent cells in an excel workbook.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

```
Sub PrintArray(Data, SheetName, StartRow, StartCol)

    Dim Row As Integer
    Dim Col As Integer

    Row = StartRow

    For i = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1)
        Col = StartCol
        For j = LBound(Data, 2) To UBound(Data, 2)
            Sheets(SheetName).Cells(Row, Col).Value = Data(i, j)
            Col = Col + 1
        Next j
            Row = Row + 1
    Next i

End Sub


Sub Test()

    Dim MyArray(1 To 3, 1 To 3)
    MyArray(1, 1) = 24
    MyArray(1, 2) = 21
    MyArray(1, 3) = 253674
    MyArray(2, 1) = "3/11/1999"
    MyArray(2, 2) = 6.777777777
    MyArray(2, 3) = "Test"
    MyArray(3, 1) = 1345
    MyArray(3, 2) = 42456
    MyArray(3, 3) = 60

    PrintArray MyArray, "Sheet1", 1, 1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

On the same theme as other answers, keeping it simple

```
Sub PrintArray(Data As Variant, Cl As Range)
    Cl.Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2)) = Data
End Sub


Sub Test()
    Dim MyArray() As Variant

    ReDim MyArray(1 To 3, 1 To 3) ' make it flexible

    ' Fill array
    '  ...

    PrintArray MyArray, ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").[A1]
End Sub
```

Comment: For OLE Automation's sake, assigning to `Range` actually means assigning to its `.Value`.

Answer (score 4):

Create a variant array (easiest by reading equivalent range in to a variant variable).

Then fill the array, and assign the array directly to the range.

```
Dim myArray As Variant

myArray = Range("blahblah")

Range("bingbing") = myArray
```

The variant array will end up as a 2-D matrix.

Answer (score 3):

A more elegant way is to assign the whole array at once:

```
Sub PrintArray(Data, SheetName, StartRow, StartCol)

    Dim Rng As Range

    With Sheets(SheetName)
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(StartRow, StartCol), _
            .Cells(UBound(Data, 1) - LBound(Data, 1) + StartRow, _
            UBound(Data, 2) - LBound(Data, 2) + StartCol))
    End With
    Rng.Value2 = Data

End Sub
```

But watch out: it only works up to a size of about 8,000 cells. Then Excel throws a strange error. The maximum size isn't fixed and differs very much from Excel installation to Excel installation.

Answer (score 3):

As others have suggested, you can directly write a 2-dimensional array into a Range on sheet, however if your array is single-dimensional then you have two options:

1. Convert your 1D array into a 2D array first, then print it on sheet (as a Range).
2. Convert your 1D array into a string and print it in a single cell (as a String).

Here is an example depicting both options:

> ```
> Sub PrintArrayIn1Cell(myArr As Variant, cell As Range)
>     cell = Join(myArr, ",")
> End Sub
> Sub PrintArrayAsRange(myArr As Variant, cell As Range)
>     cell.Resize(UBound(myArr, 1), UBound(myArr, 2)) = myArr
> End Sub
> Sub TestPrintArrayIntoSheet()  '2dArrayToSheet
>     Dim arr As Variant
>     arr = Split("a  b  c", "  ")
>
>     'Printing in ONE-CELL: To print all array-elements as a single string separated by comma (a,b,c):
>     PrintArrayIn1Cell arr, [A1]
>
>     'Printing in SEPARATE-CELLS: To print array-elements in separate cells:
>     Dim arr2D As Variant
>     arr2D = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr) 'convert a 1D array into 2D array
>     PrintArrayAsRange arr2D, Range("B1:B3")
> End Sub
> ```

Note: Transpose will render column-by-column output, to get row-by-row output transpose it again - hope that makes sense.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

My tested version

```
Sub PrintArray(RowPrint, ColPrint, ArrayName, WorkSheetName)

Sheets(WorkSheetName).Range(Cells(RowPrint, ColPrint), _
Cells(RowPrint + UBound(ArrayName, 2) - 1, _
ColPrint + UBound(ArrayName, 1) - 1)) = _
WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ArrayName)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a Range, the size of your array and use it's value property:

```
Sub PrintArray(Data, SheetName As String, intStartRow As Integer, intStartCol As Integer)

    Dim oWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim rngCopyTo As Range
    Set oWorksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName)

    ' size of array
    Dim intEndRow As Integer
    Dim intEndCol As Integer
    intEndRow = UBound(Data, 1)
    intEndCol = UBound(Data, 2)

    Set rngCopyTo = oWorksheet.Range(oWorksheet.Cells(intStartRow, intStartCol), oWorksheet.Cells(intEndRow, intEndCol))
    rngCopyTo.Value = Data

End Sub
```