# Output an function result array to worksheet with VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, function

**Scenario:** I have a function that does the capping procedure on weights of components of a set.

**Problem:** When I try to output my result output array to the excel worksheet, I keep getting an value error (on the excel cell where the function is applied)

**What I already tried:** I tried the answers in this [Excel VBA function to print an array to the workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063672/excel-vba-function-to-print-an-array-to-the-workbook)

but I still the get same error

**Question:** How can I properly do this procedure? Is the fact that I am using a function problematic for this operation?

**Relevant part of the code:** (dim parts and other basic operations were removed to maintain brevity of the question)

```
Function Capping(ISIN As Range, Sector As Range, Weights As Range, W1 As Double, W2 As Double) As Variant

le = UBound(ArISIN)
ReDim Preserve ArCap(le, 8, 1)

For c = 1 To le
    ArCap(c, 1, 1) = ArISIN(c, 1)
    ArCap(c, 2, 1) = ArSector(c, 1)
    ArCap(c, 3, 1) = ArWeight(c, 1)
Next c

For c = 1 To le
    s = 0
    For i = 1 To le
        If ArCap(c, 2, 1) = ArCap(i, 2, 1) Then
            s = s + ArCap(i, 3, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    ArCap(c, 4, 1) = s
Next c

For c = 1 To le
    If ArCap(c, 4, 1) >= W2 Then
        ArCap(c, 5, 1) = 0.03
        ArCap(c, 6, 1) = 0.03 / ArCap(c, 3, 1) * ArCap(c, 4, 1)
    Else
        ArCap(c, 5, 1) = "Not Capped"
    End If
Next c

suc = 0
scap = 0
For c = 1 To le
    If ArCap(c, 5, 1) <> "Not Capped" Then
        scap = scap + ArCap(c, 6, 1)
    Else
        suc = suc + ArCap(c, 3, 1)
    End If
Next c

For c = 1 To le
    If ArCap(c, 5, 1) = 0.03 Then
        ArCap(c, 7, 1) = ArCap(c, 6, 1)
    Else
        ArCap(c, 7, 1) = ArCap(c, 3, 1) / suc * (1 - s)
    End If
Next c

For c = 1 To le
    s = 0
    For i = 1 To le
        If ArCap(c, 2, 1) = ArCap(i, 2, 1) Then
            s = s + ArCap(i, 7, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    ArCap(c, 8, 1) = s
Next c

ReDim Preserve OutArray(le, 0)
For c = 1 To le
    OutArray(c, 0) = ArCap(c, 7, 1)
Next c

'this is where I am having problems:    
ActiveSheet.Range("A4:UC4").Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(OutArray)
```

Comment: Test your function by calling it from a separate Sub - that way you'll be able to debug any errors instead of just getting a value error in a worksheet cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return the value back through the function and not write it directly through to your sheet. Last line would look something like:

```
Capping = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(OutArray)
```

And you would be calling this function as a formula in your intended cells. Otherwise you should write this as a subroutine rather than a function.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing the result on a single row, so a 1D array is enough to hold the data:

```
ReDim OutArray(1 To le)

For c = 1 To le
    OutArray(c) = ArCap(c, 7, 1)
Next

ActiveSheet.Range("A4").Resize(1, le) = OutArray
```