# VBA how to dump a 2D array into a worksheet Range

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm looking for the **nice and elegant solution** to achieve this working code below. I could NOT find it after many searches and tries, since VBA rationales keep kind of magic for me.

The looping code :

```
Public Sub Array2Range(My2DArray As Variant, aWS As Worksheet)
' Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063672/excel-vba-function-to-print-an-array-to-the-workbook
' Ref : http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/sort-array.htm
' Ref : https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/14194-vba-arrays-examples-please-how-read-range-th.html
' Ref : https://bettersolutions.com/excel/cells-ranges/vba-working-with-arrays.htm
' Usage : Array2Range MyArray, aWS

  Dim i, j As Integer
  Dim elt As Variant

  For i = 1 To UBound(My2DArray) - LBound(My2DArray) + 1
      j = 1
     For Each elt In My2DArray(i)
        aWS.Cells(j, i) = elt
        j = j + 1
      Next elt
  Next i

End Sub
```

The watches window screenshot, to understand the 2D array structure
[image]

Thx for your support and ideas.

Comment: `aWs.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(My2DArray,1) - LBound(My2DArray,1) + 1,UBound(My2DArray,2) - LBound(My2DArray,2) + 1).Value = My2DArray`

Comment: any reason for using array of arrays (`(i)(j)`) instead of 2D rectangular array (`(i, j)`) ? You can use @ScottCraner's comment if you use 2D array

Comment: @ScottCraner Thx, this leads to `subscript out of range`. Also I swapped i and j in the code as I want the data in columns.

Comment: All the rest of the code works with using that array, so I'm not aiming to change it and introduce further bugs. I understand it would make it easier if rectangular.

Comment: Then looping is your only choice.

Comment: oh never mind .. I just noticed that the sub-arrays have different number of items

Comment: Yes, I expected to be able to code it cleaner, say dumping data by columns using `range(..).resize(..)=arr` in function of the vector size. At least getting rid off one of the 2 loops.

Comment: so you want each "Row" in the array to be a column?

Comment: Yes it would be nice to have what you can see on the screenshot into one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this eliminates one loop:

```
Public Sub Array2Range(My2DArray As Variant, aWS As Worksheet)
' Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063672/excel-vba-function-to-print-an-array-to-the-workbook
' Ref : http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/sort-array.htm
' Ref : https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/14194-vba-arrays-examples-please-how-read-range-th.html
' Ref : https://bettersolutions.com/excel/cells-ranges/vba-working-with-arrays.htm
' Usage : Array2Range MyArray, aWS

  Dim i as Long


  For i = 1 To UBound(My2DArray) - LBound(My2DArray) + 1
      aWS.Cells(1, i).Resize(UBound(My2DArray(i))).Value = Application.Transpose(My2DArray(i))
  Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thx Impressive ! Tested and works like a charm. I was not far away on one of 1000 of tries :-)

Comment: This will fail if LBound of My2DArray is not 1

Answer (score 1):

Similar, but a bit different alternative:

```
Sub ArrayToRange(jaggedArray, cell As Range): Dim subArray
    For Each subArray In jaggedArray
        cell.Resize(UBound(subArray), 1) = Application.Transpose(subArray)
        Set cell = cell(, 2)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thx Slai, looks also as an elegant solution.