# Need help returning an array from VBA into Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I would like to return the value of `compZ` into my excel data sheet. If you could tell me how to do so, I would really appreciate it.

The code is attached below:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Public Function valZ120() As Double

'declare variables

Dim equation As Double
Dim x As Double
Dim randint As String
Dim compZ(476) As Double
Dim derEq As Double
Dim valX As Double
Dim nvalX As Double
Dim varA As Double
Dim varB As Double
Dim i As Double

'loop from i=25 to i=500

For i = 25 To 500
   varA = (0.538083613 * 13736.62195 * i) / ((8.3145 ^ 2) * (120 ^ 2))
   varB = (2.528160538 * i) / (8.3145 * 120)
   x = 0
   nvalX = 0.2

   'a Do While loop

   Do While Abs(nvalX - x) >= (0.01)
      x = nvalX
      equation = (x ^ 3) - (x ^ 2) + (x * (varA - varB - varB ^ 2)) - (varA * varB)
      derEq = (3 * x ^ 2) - (2 * x) + (varA - varB - varB ^ 2)
      nvalX = (x) - ((equation) / (derEq))
   Loop

   'once the do while loop is complete, the value obtained is stored in the first space in the array and so on
   compZ(i - 24) = nvalX
   'this was just to test the code to make sure it was working (it is)
   MsgBox compZ(i - 24)
Next

'how do I bring the values of this array into excel?

End Function
```

---

Thank You

Comment: Can  you fix your line spacing and indentation?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Is this to an existing spreadsheet or do you just need to open it up in Excel?  I push a lot of things to [csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191560/create-csv-from-array-in-vba)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel VBA function to print an array to the workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063672/excel-vba-function-to-print-an-array-to-the-workbook)

Comment: Hi @abdullahq7 - you might want to have a look at some of these pages for inserting an array into excel. Since VBA is hooked up to excel, it should not be complicated. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063672/excel-vba-function-to-print-an-array-to-the-workbook

https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/array.html

Comment: Take a look at Chip Pearson's [VBA Arrays and Worksheet Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a 1 dimensional array. Should be easy right?

First check the bounds of your array, then run a for-loop through the array to output to a cell.

```
Dim arrayLength as int
arrayLength = UBound(compZ) - LBound(compZ) + 1

For i = 1 To arrayLength      
       Cells(2,i).Value = compZ(i)  
Next i
```